# Taking over a project running on EC2 and having access issues

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, key

I've recently been hired to take over a website. The last developer really gave the guys a run around, and subsequently left them high and dry. I'm now attempting to access the server instances on AWS' EC2 system. However, I obviously don't have access to the key pair required and also am unsure about getting past any password protection(I obviously can't test this until I have the correct key anyway) Can anyone suggest a way for me to at least save the data?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the data is being stored. If its on EBS volumes, getting access to it should be easy. Create a new instance with a new key, and attach volumes from an exiting instance. You should be able to mount that volume and replace the key pair stored on the volume.

Now if ephemeral volumes are being used, you wont have many options. Ephemeral volumes are lost when an instance is stopped.